# How to delete feature branches that is already feature completed

Tags: git, git-flow

How to delete feature branches that is already feature completed?

In my local machine when I run 'git branch' I still see old branches that no longer exist in the remote repo.

I tried running: 'git fetch -p'

It says deleted on some branch, but when I run 'git branch', they are still there.

Is there a way to delete them all with one command?

Comment: `git branch -d branchToRemove`

Comment: I would like to remove the local branches with no remote counter parts all at the same time. We have 30-40 branches currently, so removing one by one would require some effort.

Comment: I updated my answer with a script (untested) that might work for automating this kind of local-branch delete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In git, you have "branches", which are yours and yours alone; and then you have "remote branches", which—despite the name—are actually local, but are created and deleted bases on the branches your git sees whenever it contacts a remote git and asks it: "hey, what branches do you have over there?"

When you run `git fetch -p` it contacts your remote (usually `origin`) and gets its list of branches, and then deletes the *remote branches* that are gone on the remote.

When a remote branch like `feature` exists and you do `git checkout feature`, that creates a *local* branch called `feature`, that "tracks" your remote-branch known as `origin/feature`.  When they, on the remote, delete their `feature`, your `git fetch -p` only deletes the `remote/feature` branch.  So there's nothing left for your local branch to track, but `git fetch` won't delete your local `feature`, only `origin/feature`.  Just because *they* are done with theirs, does not mean you are done with yours.

If you *are* done with yours, you should just delete it yourself:

```
git branch -d feature
```

This will give you an error message if there are some commit(s) that will become "unreachable".  If it does, but you're **really sure** you want to delete it anyway, use a capital-D delete:

```
git branch -D feature
```

to delete it anyway.  Be careful, as a typo here that deletes the wrong thing can make for some terrible hours of recovering stuff.

---

Edit to add, per comments on original posting: if you want to automate the deletion of local branches that have an upstream set, but the upstream itself is gone, you would need a script to do it.  Something like this (totally untested) is likely to work:

```
#! /bin/sh

git for-each-ref --format '%(refname:short)' refs/heads |
while read branch; do
    # $branch is the local branch, see if it has an upstream configured
    remote=$(git config --get branch.$branch.remote) || continue
    upstream=$(git config --get branch.$branch.merge) || continue
    # $branch is configured with an upstream
    [ "$remote" = "." ] && continue # upstream is local: skip

    # If remote branch still exists, skip this local branch.
    # Note: assumes remote.$remote.fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/$remote/*
    # We could try to parse remote.$remote.fetch lines but that is too hard
    # for me to just type in as a throwaway script on SO.
    git rev-parse -q --verify $remote/$upstream >/dev/null && continue
    echo "$branch is configured to track $remote/$upstream but that's gone"
    echo "I'll try a safe delete here"
    git branch -d $branch
done
```

(I would not use `git branch -D` here, that's too dangerous.)

Answer (score 0):

I found something that can delete all obsolete branches:

```
git branch --merged | xargs git branch -d
```